# Is it legal for reverse lights to turn on when a car is in park?

Tags: united-states, michigan, transportation

This question is about the reverse lights, or backup lights, or the white lights on the back of a car:

[image]

When I am in a parking lot, some cars have the reverse lights on even though the car is in park, and has not been shifted into the reverse gear, and is not actively backing up. I have found this irritating for some time, but after reading a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Michigan/comments/brqmf1/gms_irritating_courtesy_lights_may_actually/), recently, began to wonder if it is legal or not.

Comment: Assuming you mean in Michigan, then? While many states share a lot of similar laws here, vehicle safety laws are entirely state-specific, so you'd need to specify where.

Comment: @animuson Is it state specific? Yes, then Michigan.

Comment: How do you know they're not in reverse gear but have the hand brake on?

Comment: The linked Reddit post already cites the exact section of Michigan law showing that this is not legal (Vehicle Code 257.698 (3)) so I'm not sure what else this question is looking for.  Since automakers generally know the law, it's unlikely that the car is designed to have backing lights while in park; it could be malfunctioning or somehow modified by the owner, but as Rock Ape says, the simplest explanation is that the driver has in fact (unwisely) shifted into reverse.